# Tag <permission> attribute name has invalid character '$'

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Error:

> (42, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android]
>   D:....\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:42: Tag 
>   attribute name has invalid character '$'.

[image]

When I imported my hybrid application to android studio in androidmanifest.xml file it is showing an error uses-permission attribute has invalid character '$' can any one give solution how to resolve this issue?

Comment: mind giving us the line at 72 instead of giving us a picture?

Comment: particularly since the picture is not showing line numbers?

Comment: @AbAppletic its in <users-permission android:name="${applicationId}....."/>

Comment: Try to remove the $

Comment: @AbAppetic. ${applicationId} looking for value(string or application ID name) i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use like this

```
<permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

where **com.example.myapp is your package name**

I hope it might help you !